# How to set and get viewparameter in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, viewparams

Im trying to send data from one jsf page to another, but without success.

**firstPage.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable id="dataList" value="#{firstBean.dataList}" var="data">
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">Column 1</f:facet>                            
#{data.column1.id}
</p:column>

<p:column>
<f:facet name="header" >Column 2</f:facet>                            
#{data.colum2.name}
</p:column>

<p:column>
<f:facet name="header" >Detail Row</f:facet>                            
<!-- I need this button send me to another page where i will detail information about an certain id -->
<h:commandButton value="Detalhar" action="#{firstBean.someMethod}">
<f:param name="dataId" value="#{data.column1.id}"/>
</h:commandButton>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**First Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FirstBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//list with some data
private List<Data> dataList; //getter setter

@EJB
MyDataManager manager;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
dataList = manager.getDataList();
}

public void someMethod() throws IOException {
//do something
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("secondPage.xhtml");
}
}
```

**secondPage.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="dataId" value="#{secondBean.dataDetailId}" />
<f:viewAction action="#{secondBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>

<p:dataTable value="#{secondBean.dataDetailList}" var="dataDetail">
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">Data Detail 1</f:facet>                            
#{dataDetail.data1}
</p:column>

<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">Data Detail 2</f:facet>                            
#{dataDetail.data2}
</p:column>

<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">Data Detail 3</f:facet>                            
#{dataDetail.data3}
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:body>
```

**Second Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CarteiraDetalheBean implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer dataId; //getter setter
private List<DataDetail> dataDetailList; //getter setter


@EJB
MyDataManager manager;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
dataDetailList = manager.getDataDetail(dataId);
}
}
```

When i use:

```
<f:viewAction action="#{secondBean.init}" />
```

I gotthe message: The metadata component needs to be nested within a f:metadata tag. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within

and when i use:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{secondBean.init()}" />
```

i got a null pointer exception in line:

```
dataDetailList = manager.getDataDetail(dataId);
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("secondPage.xhtml"); you could return just "secondPage" (the string)

Comment: In the second page, I think you need to add a f:metadata tag (before h:head) with tags f:viewParam (the param you're expecting) and f:event type="preRenderView" (the method that will handle it)

Comment: then in the second page MB, inside the method pointed by the preRenderView event, you can get the parameter you're sending using facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("dataId");